# JQuery persistent toggle div

Tags: jquery, local-storage, toggle

I'm new to Javascript and struggling with a persistent toggle.

I'm trying to adapt the code outlined here [Toggle DIV state localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215149/toggle-div-state-localstorage)
but my local storage variable isn't being defined.

HTML

```
<div class="oo-adv-search">
   <a id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>advanced search</a>
</div>
<div id="adv_search" class="oo-adv-search-box">
    search box content
</div>
```

CSS

```
.oo-adv-search {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

.oo-adv-search-box {
    display:none;
}
```

JScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var opened =  window.localStorage.getItem('opened');

    $('.oo-adv-search-box').hide();
        if(opened !== ''){
            $('#' + opened).find('.oo-adv-search-box').show();
        }

    $('.oo-adv-search').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).next(".oo-adv-search-box").slideToggle(500);
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        window.localStorage.setItem('opened', id);
    });
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/woodbine/0krzr949/

Comment: You forgot to include `jquery` file in your fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because you haven't include jQuery in it, and you're also traversing to an element which doesn't exist using `$(this).parent().attr('id')` - `this` is `.oo-adv-search` which has no parent in your HTML sample, hence `id` is always undefined.

Comment: Apologies. jQuery now added.

Comment: Hi Rory, not sure how to add appropriate parentage in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your fiddle and as i understand you simply want to toggle visibility of advanced search div, there is no need to set a flag in localStorage for this, just check if the element is visible.

```
$("#hideshow").on('click',function() {
    if($("#adv_search").is(":visible")) { // hide div if visible
        $("#adv_search").hide();
    } else {
        $("#adv_search").show(); // if not visible show
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0krzr949/5/)

Comment: I need the toggle to be persistent, so it has to stay there after page load.

Comment: @woodbine that is why you include localStorage?

Comment: Yes it is. I need the local storage to set a variable so that I can opt to display the advanced search options with the search results on the following page.